# How I can make validation to the Name attribute to ensure it is not empty on js?

Tags: javascript, validation

I need make validation to the Name attribute. May be need validation that it's not number?
My code:

```js
class Book {
    get name(){
        return this._name;
    }

    set name(value){
        if (value.length === 0){
            console.log("name is too short")      
        }

        this._name = value;
    } 
}
```

But not working. What wrong?

Comment: What isn't working? Please add more details, your question is quite unclear.

Comment: I want make validation for atribute Name, but maybe check if not Number? What mean validation? Or regular expression?

Comment: Javascript can check if variable has truthy value or not with just `if (value)`, will return `false` if value is `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`, `empty string ("")`, `false`